# What is the most efficient Java implementation for a real time game server?

Tags: java, tcp, udp, real-time

I'm planning on building a Java server that will handle real time game communications between clients. What is the best type of Java implementation out there that could efficiently and, hopefully, accurately communicate between a client and server at high speeds (say 5-15 packets per second)? I know there are many types of Java networking APIs (ie. ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream, DatagramPacket, KyroNet, etc.), but I'm not sure what is the most effective and/or commonly used implementation for such a scenario. I would assume that most real time games use UDP communication methods, but I understand the reliability issues that come with it. Are there UDP implementations that have some form of flow control? Anyway, thanks in advance!

Comment: 15 packets a second is not high speed. 100k packets/sec is.

Comment: I was reading a Valve article about how they made their Source servers, they said that theirs was on average 20-30 packets per second. Since I'm actually building a much smaller scale game, I don't need as many. I think 100,000 packets in one second would take up quite some bandwidth don't you think?

Comment: Is losing a packet of any significance? If not, then I would go for UDP (DatagramPacket) with a very simple checksum and just throw away the bad packages. It might be a good idea to establish the connection itself with TCP though.

Comment: Well of course losing packets is always bad, and may require the client to compensate for such events, but is it not uncommon for servers and clients to have both TCP and UDP connections going at the same time? That is, the TCP connection helps maintain the integrity of the faster moving UDP connection?

Comment: your own! none of the above is efficient. UDP might be cool but it will start fading w/ more players interacting. 20-30 per client might sound right. I'd pick custom build TCP NIO based.

Comment: Why not just use NIO, but for that slow of a speed how much will the server be doing? If maintainability is important, you may want to look at Groovy or Scala, for example, as, you take a performance hit, but there are benefits for both of these, and they can handle this slow of a speed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- **Java NIO is really good**, and can handle the kind of throughput/latency you are looking for. Don't use any of the older networking / serialization frameworks and APIs
- **Latency** is really important. You basically want a minimal layer over NIO that allows you to send very fast, small, inidividual messages with minimal overhead.
- Depending on the game, you may want **TCP or UDP or both**. Use TCP for important messages, UDP for messages that aren't strictly necessary for the game to proceed or will be subsumed by a future update (e.g. position updates in a FPS)
- Some people implement their own **TCP-like messaging protocol over UDP** for real time games. This is probably more hassle than it's worth, but be aware of it as an option if you *really* need to optimise for a specific type of communication
- For real time games, you are nearly always doing **custom serialisation** (e.g. only sending deltas rather than full updates of object positions) - so make sure your framework allows this

Given this, I'd recommend one of the following

- [Kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) - lightwieght, customisable, designed for this kind of purpose
- [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) - slightly more enterprise-oriented, but very capable, robust and scalable
- Roll-your-own based on NIO - tricky but possible if you want really fine grained control. I've done this before, but in retrospect I probably should have picked Kryonet or Netty

Good luck!

Comment: btw sync between UDP+TCP is a hard one to crack, and it can be a serious source of 'hacking' issues for the server.  IMO, custom NIO is not so hard but I guess the question would have no been asked in the 1st place. Knowing when to use the direct buffers takes experience as well, my take is a direct buffer per client and capacity of the socket snd buffer size.

Comment: Just one more question, what is the main advantage of using the newer NIO API. Of course it's newer so its probably better, but what difference does it make in comparison to using traditional Sockets and ServerSockets?

Comment: The main advantage of NIO is that it harnesses lower level constructs in the operating system - so you can do data transfers with lower overheads, handle event-driven asynchronous responses with selectors etc.

Comment: fast-serialization + fast-cast + netty is a decent combo for clustered high performance apps

Answer (score 1):

Immidiately forget ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. These are the standard output-input mechanisms of the old standard java serialization, which is slow and produces bloat objects. Some resources to start with:

- http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/
- http://code.google.com/p/pyronet/